# How can I get the Api key of an existing facebook application

Tags: facebook

I've created a facebook APP and I don't know where to find the Api Key. For some reason the page http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php returns a partial response. I don't know where to find the Api key.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: What do you mean by partial response?

Comment: When I tried viewing the response, it only had the <head> tag and 2 inner <link> tags. The rest was not parsed for some reason. The same happens for the app page. I tried on multiple browsers but to no avail. I tried another account and it worked fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://www.facebook.com/developers/, click on your app. Then you should see the following screen:

[image]

If you can't find your app, go to: http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID